# How to simplify this C# code?

Tags: c#

I want to get a string (str) by using below statements, it works but any suggestions to formulate this control?
because count can be "n".

```
 if (a.count== 0)
 {
    str += a.Name;
 }
    else if (a.count== 1)
 {
    str += a.Parent.Name + "/" +  a.Name;
 }
 else if (a.count== 2)
 {
    str += a.Parent.Parent.Name + "/" + a.Parent.Name + "/" + a.Name;
 }
 else if (a.count== 3)
 {
    str += a.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name + "/" +a.Parent.Parent.Name + "/" + a.Parent.Name + "/" + a.Name;
 }
 . 
 .
 .
 else if(a.count = n)
 {
         //n times..
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "formulate"? It is not a standard phrase.

Comment: You should look into "loops", or try to figure "recursivity"

Comment: I mean, can I use recursive function or any loop to make it in less line of code (:

Comment: You can tidy it up using switch/case break default;

Comment: Can you modify the code of the parent property? If yes, you should add some code in this class, to simplify the writing. How is the a.count method computed? Are you working with a custom tree?

Comment: @HatSoft - Um. No, you can't. Not with an unbounded number of levels.

Comment: Instead of "formulate" I would say - "clean up" or "reduce lines of code"...

Comment: Thanks for standard phrase advice Oded. You are right.. I graduated from Maths so you know.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following (but you'll need to play with it to make it work):

```
int count = a.count;
var current = a;
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
    str += (i > 0 ? "/" : string.empty) + current.Name;
    current = current.Parent;
}
```

There're obviously a lot of corner cases, which you need to take into account.

Comment: I will try, it seems really cool :)

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop is a bad idea, you should use `StringBuilder` instead. Also, doesn't this combine the parts in the wrong order?

Comment: @svick completely agree. That's why I wrote that it's not a final version of the code, but just an idea. There's a lot of room for improvement, one of them is the string concatenation part.

Answer (score 2):

maybe count is not needed if you stop when parent is null, 
and I think that using Path.Combine is more elegant :)

```
 var node = a;
 while (node != null) {
    str = Path.Combine(node.Name, str);
    node = node.Parent;
 }
```

or you can use a extension method to calculate it for you:

```
 public static class Extension {

      public static string GetFullPath( this YourNodeType node)
      {
           return (node.Parent == null) 
             ? node.Name 
             : Path.Combine( node.Parent.GetFullPath(), node.Name);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would

- create an Enumerator on the type of A that returns itself and its parent hierarchy
- with LINQ select the Name-property
- Reverse() the result
- use string.Join with the slash to create the string

Comment: this can be best method but it seems really hard for me , at least today.. but thanx for quick reply flq..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
object unknownparent;
for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
{
unknownparent = a.Parent;
    for(int j = i; j<n; j++)
    {
        unknownparent = ((typeofa)unknownparent).Parent;
    }

    str += ((typeofa)unknownparent).Parent.Name + "/";

}
str += a.Name;
```

Comment: Sergiu, this doesn't work. Notice how the code in the question builds up the string from the names of the control's ancestors.

Comment: and I think for the a.Parent I have to use one more for inside, isn't it?